# How to call another jquery script when I select a dropdown using onchange

Tags: php, jquery, html

How can I call another script and pass a id so I can fill another drop down pulling data from mysql. I have added the scripts below I just don't understand how to call them

```
$( document ).ready(function() 
{
$.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
        type: "GET",
        url: "customer.php",
        dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned
        success: function(response){                    
            $(".responsetext").html(response); 
            //alert(response);
        }
    }); 
});
```

THIS SCRIPT FILLES THE DROPDOWE BELOW USING responsetext

```
 <select name="customer"id="customer" class="form-control input-sm responsetext">
</select>
```

SO WHEN I SELECT THIS IT WILL PASS THE ID AND RUN THE SCRIPT BELOW

```
$(function() {  //  document.ready
    $("#id").on("change", function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "contact.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                id: $(this).val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $(".contactresults").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

SO IT WILL FILL THIS SELECT BOX WITH contactresults

```
    <select name="contact" class="form-control input-sm contactresults" id="contact">
                        </select>
```

Comment: try storing the `id` in a variable before the ajax call, and `alert` the variable to check it picked it up properly

Comment: change `$("#id").on("change",` to `$("#customer").on("change",`. You use the literal `id` rather than the actual id `customer`.